# Why are subsequent sibling elements still stuck floating beneath a previous sibling?

Tags: css, css-float

I want to float the red element all the way to the top right corner. However, it's top position is still beneath the element before it. Why does float behave this way? And how can I get the red element to float to the top right corner?

Example [[jsfiddle.net]](https://jsfiddle.net/vm6xgv6g/)

html:

```
<div class='blue'></div>
<div class='red'></div>
<div class='black'></div>
```

css:

```
div {  
    width: 100px;  
    height: 100px;  
    margin:2px;  
} 

.blue { background-color:blue; }
.red { background-color:red; }
.black { background-color:black; }

.red {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put the `<div class="red"></div>` as the first `<div>`.

See [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/vm6xgv6g/1/) on JSFiddle.

This is because `float`ed elements in CSS line up with the bottom of the previous element (or the bottom of the container element if there is no previous element).

Comment: "floated elements in CSS line up with the top of the next element". Thank for that, never heard it before. How did you find this out? Is there a specification somewhere saying this?

Comment: @cblupo Nope, just by my own experience =). But have you found anything that contradicts this?

Comment: "or the container element if there is no subsequent element." When I remove the last element (from my jsfiddle), the red block stays in the same position, even though I removed the subsequent element. Why?

Comment: @cblupo it is still lining up with the next element. Not much has changed. I don't understand why it would...

Comment: If you leave the red element second and then remove the black element, the red element stays in the same position. However, this seems to contradict part of your answer. I would expect the red element to float to the top right corner if all subsequent sibling elements were removed